# Codeigniter Upload Files/image only works when offline

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

I made a code to upload files on the web, when I was still using xampp, it always going well, but after I upload to hosting, file uploading not working..

here's my code :

**MODEL** (for updating database record)

```
function edit_logo_web()
    {
    $timestamp = date('YmdHi');
    $img = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $logo = $timestamp."_".$img;
    $data = array (
    'logo'  => $logo
    );
    $id = 1;
    $this->db->where('site.id', $id);   
    if($this->upload->do_upload()){
    $this->db->update('site', $data);}
    else{
    }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER** (for uploading img/file to web directory)

```
    function logo_web()
        {
        $timestamp = date('YmdHi');
        $img = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $config['file_name'] = $timestamp."_".$img;
        $config['upload_path'] ='asset/img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size']    = '1024';
        $config['max_width']  = '1600';
        $config['max_height']  = '1200';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->m_cmm_bimbel->edit_logo_web();
        echo "<script>
        alert('Success !!');
        window.location.href='logo_web';
        </script>";
    }
```

it Does very well in xampp localserver..
not in the hostingserver..

Any tips?

Comment: Can you try with  **$config['upload_path'] ='./asset/img/';** and make sure directory exists and you have enough read/write rights on given path.

Comment: i tried both of './asset/img/' and base_url() . 'asset/img/'

Comment: have you check permissions on directory?

Comment: of course, I have prepared everything maybe...

Comment: You must have set permission 777 of upload directory

Comment: it works great thanks!
but does it safe?

Comment: you need to block direct directory access or listing of the directory. you can achieve it by **.htaccess** file.